# Creating an array of DateTime without the time portion

Tags: c#, datetime

I've created an array of DateTime objects. However when doing so by default the array has the time portion attacthed. I need to this removed to compare to another date which is simply in the "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

Creating the array:

```
DateTime[] exclusionDates = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1) };
```

I'm trying to compare that with

```
monthlyCalendar.SelectionEnd.Date == excluHarry[0].Date
```

How do I remove the time portion to the element of the array?

Thanks.

Comment: Dates are numbers that can be represented as strings. When you compare them, numbers are compared, so there's no need to strip the time portion...

Comment: Yea, sorry I just wasn't thinking straight. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Date from a DateTime object will get you what you looking for without having to got to string conversion. I have attached example code with two DateTime  objects with same date but with different times. The if statement compares only the date portion. Please do accept the answer that helped you the most. Welcome to stack overflow

```
using System;

namespace DateObject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime[] exDates = new DateTime[] {new DateTime(2017, 1, 1)};
            var dt = exDates[0].Date;

            //new date with a different time
            DateTime t = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 5, 30, 23);

            //compare the two for date part only --exclude the time in the comparision
            if (dt.Equals(t.Date))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dates are the same without comparing the time");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are already excluding the time portion when you use the `.Date` on the `DateTime` object.

Also, a DateTime object has no format, it only gets a format when you call `.ToString()` on it, your `monthlyCalendar` object calls `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` internally before displaying it to the user, that is the only reason you see it  in that form from the user's perspective.

Comment: Thanks for you help.